# Getting coordinates to near me using node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I am using Node.JS, MongoDB and express.js. I keep coordinates in my database. And I want to get the coordinates to near me. How can I do it?

I thought about converting the meridians to km. I was able to calculate at the equator, but due to the shape of the earth, the distance between the meridian was not equal everywhere. I couldn't find any other solution.

My coordinate parameter in Mongo Model:
coordinate: {
type: String,
},

Example value:

coordinate: "41.08112226606513,29.066728949546814"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   {
   <location field>: {
     $near: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
       },
       $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
       $minDistance: <distance in meters>
     }
   }
}
```

use this above query in your query

please read this above official [document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)

Comment: I haven't tested the minimum distance, but there is a problem with the maximum distance. I have 2 coordinates.
1: my coordinate
2: Target coordinate

sorghum:
$near: {
$geometry: {
     type: "Point" ,
     coordinates: [40.10522441484051,27.177925397689176]
     },
     $minDistance: 0,
     $maxDistance: 1890000
}

data i got:
"places": [
         {
           "id": "6329f144b2549a683c0184ad",
           "name": "Test",
           "coordinate": "39.10525792669665, 27.17787548271122",
           coordinates: [39.10525792669665,27.17787548271122]
         }
       ]

Comment: When I make the max distance 120000(120km) as it should be, I get an empty array. How can I fix?

Comment: I am using the 2dsphere index.